# Preferred method to keep long-running client alive in Python asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I'd like to keep a client app running that uses async.run to start its main function:

```
async def main():
    nc = await nats.connect(nats_url)
    js = nc.jetstream()

    await js.add_stream(name=stream, subjects=[subject])

    await js.subscribe(subject, qgroup, cb=do_work)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Running as above, of course, the program completes immediately. What's the preferred way to keep a client running using asyncio?

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the Python asyncio docs, the closest example i found is this:

Note the asyncio.sleep inside a loop, similar to the traditional pattern of an infinite loop around a blocking function.

```
async def main():
    nc = await nats.connect(nats_url)
    js = nc.jetstream()

    await js.add_stream(name=stream, subjects=[subject])

    await js.subscribe(subject, qgroup, cb=do_work)

    while True:
        print("loop")
        await asyncio.sleep(10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know js but for a regular nats client instead of

```py
while True:
   print("loop")
   await asyncio.sleep(10)
```

you should add

```py
 nc.wait(count=1000)
```

for getting 1000 messages, or

```py
while True:
   print('got a new message:')
   nc.wait(count=1)
```

for running forever